# doWithDynamicMethods access Service

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am having difficulty to access particular Service within doWithDynamicMethod.

```
def doWithDynamicMethods = { ctx ->
        def nodeDriverProxy  = application.getServiceClass('NodeDriverProxyService')
        application.domainClasses.each{ cClass ->
            delegate.log.warn('cClass: ' + cClass.toString())
            cClass.metaClass.cacheInstance = { domainIns->
                delegate.log.warn "domain is being cached id: ? with version ?"
                nodeDriverProxy.registerUpdate(domainIns.id, domainIns.version)
            }
```

the variable nodeDriveProxy is null or i got exception when accessing 'application.serviceClasses' What am i doing wrong? Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the `GrailsServiceClass`, you want the service instance. You have the `ctx` variable which is the Spring `ApplicationContext`, so it would be

```
def doWithDynamicMethods = { ctx ->
   def service = ctx.nodeDriverProxyService
   application.domainClasses.each { cClass ->
      delegate.log.warn('cClass: ' + cClass.toString())
      cClass.metaClass.cacheInstance = { domainIns ->
         delegate.log.warn "domain is being cached id: ? with version ?"
         service.registerUpdate(domainIns.id, domainIns.version)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Burt. you are truly great. I have learnt so much from your other answers to other grails developers. thanks for helping